# How to reference an existing css content-based icon, within my admin menu hook

Tags: admin-menu, admin-css

Within WordPress 4.6.1, I really like the thumbtack icon that is being used in the admin menus.  This is the thumbtack icon (generated in CSS) that I am referring to...

[image]

I'm currently using the WordPress API to generate my own menu with the following admin menu hook...

```
    add_menu_page('Cool Plugin Page', 'Cool Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my_main_menu','my_main_plugin_page', plugins_url('/images/thumbtack-icon.jpg',__FILE__));
```

So how do I replace the `plugins_url()` portion within my hook with the same css thumbtack that WordPress is using for the other menu section? When I view source through developer tools, I see it looks like this...

```
.dashicons-admin-post:before, .dashicons-format-standard:before {
    content: "\f109";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses [Dashicons](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#admin-post%20Dashicons). Basically you would replace your code with this: 
`add_menu_page('Cool Plugin Page', 'Cool Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my_main_menu','my_main_plugin_page', 'dashicons-admin-post', '');`

Comment: Very nice!  This is almost like having font-awesome built into Wordpress!  Thank you so much!